# Suppress chrome's first-time dialog on linux

Tags: linux, automation, automated-install, google-chrome

I'm trying to install google chrome using puppet on a bunch of linux machines (SLES 12) and I don't want any dialogs that the user has to answer before they can start browsing. This is mainly because the "user" will be Selenium and it doesn't like unexpected things.

I can't for the life of me stop the dialog that asks me two questions:

[image]

I'm going mad. I've tried every preference (via master_preferences) I can find and it still haunts me. My master_preferences:

```
{
    "homepage" : "http://www.puppetlabs.com",
    "homepage_is_newtabpage": false,
    "distribution" : {
        "ready_mode" : true,
        "skip_first_run_ui" : true,
        "suppress_first_run_bubble": true,
        "suppress_first_run_default_browser_prompt" : true,
        "show_welcome_page" : false,
        "make_chrome_default" : false
    },
    "first_run_tabs" : [
        "new_tab_page"
    ],
    "browser" : {
        "check_default_browser" : false,
        "suppress_first_run_default_browser_prompt" : true
    },
    "sync_promo" : {
        "show_on_first_run_allowed" : false
    },
    "show-first-run-bubble-option": 0
}
```

I can't find any relevant policy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this setting:
http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#MetricsReportingEnabled

You may also need to enforce the setting to make (or not make) Chrome the default browser: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultBrowserSettingEnabled

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you described by starting the browser then close it then start it again (for the same user data directory), this worked for me on Linux and I got no popup in the second startup.

Else, if you have access to the user data dir, you can create the file `First Run` (with space) in the root of it, with empty content, then no popup should be shown on the first startup.